# Java SSL client can't establish a handshake

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate

I'm trying to implement a Java SSL client that will work with my C++ SSL server. I know the SSL server works as I've tested it with an CURL SSL client.

The problem I'm seeing when I try to connect with the Java client is it doesn't seem to be sending the client certificate, so the server throws an error saying it didn't receive a client cert.

I seem to be loading the client cert and key so I am puzzled why the server is not receiving ANY cert.

Would appreciate someone looking at my Java client code and seeing if anything jumps out at you.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
InputStream stream = null;
stream = new FileInputStream("C:\\certs\\client.keystore");
keyStore.load(stream, "changeit".toCharArray());                
System.out.println("loaded the keystore");

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("client-identity", "changeit".toCharArray());
System.out.println("private key:  " + key);
Certificate cert = (Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate("client-identity");
System.out.println("client cert:  " + cert);
kmf.init(keyStore, "changeit".toCharArray());

SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslCtx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);          

SSLSocketFactory sslSF = (SSLSocketFactory) sslCtx.getSocketFactory();
System.out.println(" Creating and opening new SSLSocket with SSLSocketFactory");

// using createSocket(String hostname, int port)
SSLSocket sslSock = (SSLSocket) sslSF.createSocket("localhost", 1111);
System.out.println(" SSLSocket created");
HandshakeCompletedListener mListener = null;
mListener = new MyListener();

sslSock.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new MyListener());
```

**Update**

This might be the issue.

```
C:\movrm-contract\https-client>keytool -list -keystore client.keystore -v
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: client.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: client.keystore
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:565)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:171)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:165)
```

But I'm not sure how to fix this. I created the JSK file from client.pem and privkey.pem files. What is the right way to import them into a Java keystore? And, does the signing CA cert need to be in that same key store?

Comment: Run your client with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake and post the output here. The server sends a list of CAs that it trusts; the client can only send a certificate that is signed by one of those, directly or indirectly.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post with the debug output. Is this enough?Does this help me?

Comment: No, the rest is the part I want to see, starting with the server's `CertificateRequest` message and the client's reply, followed shortly by an `alert`, a close, and a handshake failure.

Comment: Well, I'm not getting any of that output at all. BUT I did another update to the original post. I think I found what the problem might be. I ran keytool to list what in the key store and it gave me an exception. Take a look at my updated post. See if what I'm saying me sense. Thanks.

Comment: Well, yeah, no KeyStore, no certificate.

Comment: OK but what is the right way to import .pem files into a Java keystore? I have a private-key.pem and client.pem. The client.pem has the client and CA certificates in it. Is that a problem for keytool? I've been reading a lot of different post about problems with keytool. Frankly I'm confused about the proper way to import keys and cert into JSK file.

Comment: I believe you can treat the private-key .pem as a PCKS#12 keystore and use the -importkeystore command. Or else you convert it to PKCS#12 with the `openssl` tool and then ditto. I'm not sure which it is offhand. Same for the certificate. Or indeed once you have it all in PKCS#12 format you can use that as a keystore directly.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll try to figure out keytool. Maybe I create cert and keys from scratch with it.